# Comprobar si he podido reservar memoria matriz dinamica en C

Tags: c, matriz, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy declarando un array dinámico en C de esta forma:

```
    int m  = atoi(argv[1]); /* Filas */
    int p  = atoi(argv[2]); /* Columnas*/
    long int** matriz;


    /* Hago una reserva de memoria para mi matriz */
    matriz = (long int**) malloc(m * sizeof(long int));

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        matriz[i] = (long int*) malloc(p * sizeof(long int));
    }
```

Usualmente al reservar memoria dinamica en C tengo que comprobar si la he podido reservar
haciendo algo del estilo:

```
if(matriz == NULL){
    return (71);
}
```

En este caso no estoy seguro de si es correcto al ser mi array dinámico un doble puntero, pues al ponerle a los argumentos valores altos (para los que estoy seguro de que no puedo reservar tanta memoria debido a la máquina virtual que uso) el programa se me queda ejecutando y ni siquiera llega a meterse en el if.
¿Cómo podría comprobar si se ha podido reserva correctamente la memoria dinámica?

Comment: [La documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) suele ser un buen punto de inicio: `On failure, returns a null pointer.`

Comment: Ya sé que el malloc devuelve un null cuando falla, pero en este caso pregunto que si influye al tratarse de una matriz(doble puntero) .

Comment: Lo de que sea un puntero simple, doble, o triple, es indiferente. La función no tiene forma de saber el escenario en el que la estas usando :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas repasar el funcionamiento de los punteros.

Un puntero se diferencia de otra variable por un asterisco (`*`) entre el tipo al que apunta y su nombre.

Por ejemplo, un puntero a un entero (`int`) se declara así:

```
int* puntero;
```

Si lees el puntero que declaraste:

```
long int** matriz;
```

Es un puntero a un valor de tipo `long int*`. Es decir, es un puntero a un puntero. Son 2 niveles de indirección.

Por lo tanto está reserva de memoria está mal:

```
matriz = (long int**) malloc(m * sizeof(long int));
```

Ya que tienes que reservar memoria para valores de tipo `long int*`. Lo correcto es:

```
matriz = (long int**) malloc(m * sizeof(long int));
```

Por cierto, las conversiones no son necesarias, hay conversión implícita de `void*` a cualquier otro tipo de puntero.

---

Idealmente deberías verificar que se haya reservado la memoria correctamente:

```
matriz = malloc(m * sizeof(long int));

if (!matriz) { // Equivalente a matriz != NULL
    // Falló la reserva de memoria
}  

for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
    matriz[i] = malloc(p * sizeof(long int));
    if (!matriz[i]) {
        // Falló la reserva de memoria
    }
}
```